# wordpress taxonomies echoing them

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

I've set up a taxonomy in my functions.php of wordpress (I made it within a custom post type):

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
    function create_post_type() {
        register_post_type( 'clip',
            array(
                'labels' => array(
                    'name' => __( 'Clips' ),
                    'singular_name' => __( 'Clip' )
                ),
                'public' => true,
                'has_archive' => true,
                'hierarchical' => true,
                'supports' => array('editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'title')
            )
        );

          // Add new taxonomy, NOT hierarchical (like tags)
          $labels = array(
            'name' => _x( 'Directors', 'taxonomy general name' ),
            'singular_name' => _x( 'Director', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
            'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Directors' ),
            'popular_items' => __( 'Popular Directors' ),
            'all_items' => __( 'All Directors' ),
            'parent_item' => null,
            'parent_item_colon' => null,
            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Director' ), 
            'update_item' => __( 'Update Director' ),
            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Director' ),
            'new_item_name' => __( 'New Director Name' ),
            'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate Directors with commas' ),
            'add_or_remove_items' => __( 'Add or remove Directors' ),
            'choose_from_most_used' => __( 'Choose from the most used Directors' ),
            'menu_name' => __( 'Directors' ),
          ); 

          register_taxonomy('director','clip',array(
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'labels' => $labels,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
            'query_var' => true,
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'director' ),
          ));


    } //end clip creation PT
```

and now I want to call it out but can't seem to.

This is the method I am using but is not working.

```
echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'director', 'director: ', ', ', '' );
```

do you know how to fix this?

Comment: What is it that you want the output to be exactly? It seems like by merely amending the below code a bit, you can easily add the output you want?..

Answer (score 0):

```
$args=array(
  'name' => 'director'
);
$output = 'objects';
$taxonomies=get_taxonomies($args,$output); 
if  ($taxonomies) {
  foreach ($taxonomies  as $taxonomy ) {
    echo '<p>' . $taxonomy->name . '</p>';
  }
}
```